# OneOf inside Json-Schema picks up one case and its negation

Tags: json, jsonschema

I use a Json-schema like the one below. It consist of two definitions, `request` and `response`.

If `request` is not valid there shall be no `response` allowed. But if `request` is valid there shall be a `response`.

Here are two json examples I would assume to work:

```
{
  "request": { "valid": true },
  "response":
  {
    "uuid": "12345678901234567890123456789012",
    "datetime": "123456789012345678901234",
    "seconds": 10
  }
}
```

and

```
{
  "request": { "valid": false }
}
```

I'm asking why `oneOf` is not working as expected? A json-file like

```
{
  "request": { "valid": true }
}
```

validates as correct, even in absence of it's request-part.

The Schema:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "definitions": {
    "request": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "valid": {
          "type": "boolean",
          "description": "Request was valid or not."
        }
      },
      "required": ["valid"],
      "additionalProperties": false
    },
    "response": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "uuid": {
          "type": "string",
          "description": "UUID of person which logged in.",
          "maxLength": 36
        },
        "datetime": {
          "type": "string",
          "description": "Datetime of last interaction.",
          "maxLength": 24
        },
        "seconds": {
          "type": "integer",
          "description": "Login valid in seconds.",
          "minimum": 0
        }
      },
      "required": ["uuid", "datetime", "seconds"],
      "additionalProperties": false
    }
  },
  "title": "login response",
  "type": "object",
  "oneOf": [{
      "properties": {
        "request": {
          "valid": {
            "const": false
          }
        }
      },
      "required": ["request"],
      "additionalProperties": false
    },
    {
      "properties": {
        "request": {
          "valid": {
            "const": true
          }
        },
        "response": {
          "$ref": "#/definitions/response"
        }
      },
      "required": ["request", "response"],
      "additionalProperties": false
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Can you update with the library that you're using?  It may provide insight into what's going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your schema checking if valid is true/false. See `#/definitions/is-valid-request` in the example below. I suggest using `if`/`then`/`else` rather than `oneOf` in this case. You'll get more helpful error messages that way. Below is an example of how you might implement it.

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "title": "login response",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "request": { "$ref": "#/definitions/request" },
    "response": { "$ref": "#/definitions/response" }
  },
  "additionalProperties": false,
  "required": ["request"],
  "allOf": [{ "$ref": "#/definitions/require-response-with-valid-request" }],
  "definitions": {
    "request": { ... },
    "response": { ... },
    "require-response-with-valid-request": {
      "if": { "$ref": "#/definitions/is-valid-request" },
      "then": { "required": ["response"] },
      "else": { "not": { "required": ["response"] } }
    },
    "is-valid-request": {
      "properties": {
        "request": {
          "properties": {
            "valid": { "const": true }
          },
          "required": ["valid"]
        }
      },
      "required": ["request"]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @lahiruk actually spotted the problem. I missed it, too. It's not the `oneOf`. It's how `request` is defined. OP is missing a `properties` keyword.

Comment: Right, that's what I was pointing out at `#/definitions/is-valid-request`.

Comment: I should have done a better job of separating pointing out the error and showing an alternative. That was confusing.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like your `request` property is not defined inside `oneOf` correctly. Here are two possible solutions to this problem. Hope it will help.

**Solution 01:** Move `request` definition into each oneOf block

```
 "oneOf": [
    {
      "properties": {
        "request": {
          "type": "object",
          "properties": {
            "valid": {
              "const": false
            },
            "required": [
              "valid"
            ],
            "additionalProperties": false
          }
        }
      },
      "required": [
        "request"
      ],
      "additionalProperties": false
    },
    {
      "properties": {
        "request": {
          "type": "object",
          "properties": {
            "valid": {
              "const": true
            },
            "required": [
              "valid"
            ],
            "additionalProperties": false
          }
          }
        },
        "response": {
          "$ref": "#/definitions/response"
        }
      },
      "required": [
        "request",
        "response"
      ],
      "additionalProperties": false
    }
  ]
```

**Solution 02:** Use separate definitions for `request`

```
 "definitions": {
    "valid_request": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "valid": {
          "const": true,
          "description": "Request was valid"
        }
      },
      "required": [
        "valid"
      ],
      "additionalProperties": false
    },
    "invalid_request": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "valid": {
          "const": false,
          "description": "Request was invalid"
        }
      },
      "required": [
        "valid"
      ],
      "additionalProperties": false
    }
 }
```

```
"oneOf": [
    {
      "properties": {
        "request": {
          "$ref": "#/definitions/invalid_request"
        }
      },
      "required": [
        "request"
      ],
      "additionalProperties": false
    },
    {
      "properties": {
        "request": {
          "$ref": "#/definitions/valid_request"
        },
        "response": {
          "$ref": "#/definitions/response"
        }
      },
      "required": [
        "request",
        "response"
      ],
      "additionalProperties": false
    }
  ]
```

Comment: Nice catch. Personally, I'd go with the first option.